# Parse push targeting single device

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I want to target a single user / device while sending push notifications via the Parse REST API.

I understand that first of all, I need to create a new installation. To target a single user, I believe I need to send something that identifies a single user such as a User ID.

Here's a list of installations:

[image]

And here's a push I sent to that device targeting by `user_id``

[image]

And while the Parse push backend tells me the push was correctly sent through to the REST API, It's not getting sent to the device and the backend tells me the "number of sends" is 0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you register the user for push notifications you can assign them a channel. When we did this we had the same issue trying to use the object ID. We used the device UUID as the channel.

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/iOS

Edit:
I don't think channels can start with a number, so we put a letter at the start of each UUID, for example:
    `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];`